# nginx readonly container complains about /var/lib/nginx/off

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, containers, alpine

I am trying to run a nginx container in readonly rootfs but when nginx tries to start it complains about :

```
[emerg] 10#10: open() "/var/lib/nginx/off" failed (30: Read-only file system)
nginx: [emerg] open() "/var/lib/nginx/off" failed (30: Read-only file system)
```

Where does that file come from ?

I have already added the following to nginx.conf

```
  client_body_temp_path /tmp 1 2;
  proxy_temp_path /tmp 1 2;
  fastcgi_temp_path /tmp 1 2;
  uwsgi_temp_path /tmp 1 2;
  scgi_temp_path /tmp 1 2;
```

Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: I'd _guess_ you have `error_log off;` and it's interpreting it as a path or similar, but since your question did not include any configuration, we're left to just guess

Comment: Is your issue resolved? Seems like your nginx is not running as a root user. Try this similar [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477337/why-i-am-getting-read-only-file-system-error-from-nginx) may help to resolve your issue.